# ASCII codec can't encode character and can only concat str

Tags: python, django, unicode, request

I'm trying to send a request in Django:

```
res = self.client.get("/test/", {"var":"test"+u"\u200B".encode('utf-8')})
```

However, I keep getting the error message (random characters to add more details.........)

```
#12 1.291 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#12 1.291 Traceback (most recent call last):
#12 1.291   File "/usr/src/app/program/test_security.py", line 18, in test_should_not_register_existing_domain_with_unicode_confusable
#12 1.291     res = self.client.get("/test/", {"domain":"test"+u"\u200B".encode('utf-8')})
#12 1.291 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
#12 1.291 
#12 1.291 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I remove `.encode('utf-8')` I get the following stack trace. It wants me to add more details for this lol.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
#12 1.267 Traceback (most recent call last):
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 297, in ulabel
#12 1.267     label_bytes = label.encode('ascii')
#12 1.267 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
#12 1.267 
#12 1.267 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
#12 1.267 
#12 1.267 Traceback (most recent call last):
#12 1.267   File "/usr/src/app/program/test_security.py", line 18, in test_should_not_register_existing_domain_with_unicode_confusable
#12 1.267     res = self.client.get("/register/", {"domain":"test"+u"\u200B".encode"})
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 518, in get
#12 1.267     response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 344, in get
#12 1.267     return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **{
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 421, in generic
#12 1.267     return self.request(**r)
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 496, in request
#12 1.267     raise exc_value
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
#12 1.267     response = get_response(request)
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
#12 1.267     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
#12 1.267     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
#12 1.267   File "/usr/src/app/program/views.py", line 10, in register
#12 1.267     res = check(domain)
#12 1.267   File "/usr/src/app/program/utils.py", line 6, in check
#12 1.267     normalised_domain = idna.decode(domain).lower()
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 402, in decode
#12 1.267     s = ulabel(label)
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 299, in ulabel
#12 1.267     check_label(label)
#12 1.267   File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 263, in check_label
#12 1.267     raise InvalidCodepoint('Codepoint {} at position {} of {} not allowed'.format(_unot(cp_value), pos+1, repr(label)))
#12 1.267 idna.core.InvalidCodepoint: Codepoint U+200B at position 4 of 'test\u200bpal' not allowed
#12 1.267 
#12 1.267 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include *the full stack trace*, not simply the error message.

Comment: Done, not too sure how much more it'll really help

Comment: That is not the stack trace associated with the error message in your question title. And I think that is the one you want resolved. Put back the `.encode('utf-8')`  and report *that* stack trace.

Comment: The title is two error messages, hence the AND. I've tried two things and neither have worked. ``can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`` is self explanatory - I don't know why you'd need the full stack trace for that. It's relating directly to that line of code. I've included it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This concatenation will always fail, and it has nothing to do with the Django function you are calling:

```
"test"+"\u200Bpal".encode('utf-8')
```

The reason it fails is because `"test"` is a *string*, and `"\u200Bpal"` is a *string*, but `"\u200Bpal"` after you encode it is a `bytes`. And, as the message says, your code can only concatenate `str` (not "`bytes`") to `str`.

So if your function is expecting a `bytes` then you have to encode the whole thing after concatenation. This:

```
("test"+u"\u200Bpal").encode('utf-8')
```

will not give an error when you do the concatenation, but will result in the `bytes` value

```
b'test\xe2\x80\x8bpal'
```

and this is 10 bytes long, not the 9 you might be expecting, because UTF-8 takes 3 bytes to encode the zero-width space character.

But it may be that this will still not do what you want. Django is calling `idna` to resolve the non-ascii character in the domain name, and it does not accept the zero-width space, as the message says pretty clearly: *Codepoint U+200B at position 4 of 'test\u200bpal' not allowed*. This is because browsers generally [ban zero-width spaces](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) in domain names because of the potential for phishing.

You don't need that `u` prefix, by the way. That was a Python 2 thing and is still recognized only because in the past that made it easier to write code that would run under both versions. As you can confirm like this:

```
>>> u"\u200B"
'\u200b'
```